# Using technically impossible shutter speed when shooting video

Tags: video

I have a question about the video mode of my DSLR.

When i record i can set the frame rage (e.g. 25 fps). In that setting my DSLR should take 25 images within 1 second.

In manual (or "s" mode) mode i can set the shutter speed of the taken video. 
Technically the  maximum should be 1/25 because of the frame rate. But i can also choose values above.

Question: How is it technically possible to record a video with 25 fps having set the shutter speed more than 1/25s. ( e.g. 1/4s)

Comment: it would probably help if you told us your camera model. it's possible that it just ignores the setting.

Comment: @ths Nikon D3200 - when i change the shutter speed, the image changes aswell (lighter / darker)

Comment: I think you need to read the manual carefully.  It's not possible to expose for longer than the frame time, but it is theoretically possible to add frames together (tho' I doubt your camera is doing this).  You may find that the apparent shutter time is different when in video modes.

Comment: I once had the same question and I asked on DPReview. Have a look at the answers.. http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/56171573

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It IS possible to exposure longer that frame time. Think about a) two frames per exposure, or b) time lapse in the night ( when exposure time is far longer than 1 second and there are 25 or 30 or 50  frames in one second of the final video).

Comment: @Alex.S you're pushing the definition of "frame" way beyond reality. That's not how film, let alone solid-state, movie cameras work.

Comment: @user152435 That referenced forum confuses "transmitted frame rate" with "information update rate."  By their definition, I could expose for an hour, dupe the image 3.6 million times, and have a 100 fps movie.  It'd be damn boring.

Answer (score 1):

Whether this happens inside your specific camera is not clear. However, it is possible to have a shutter speed slower than the FPS would naively allow. In practice, it's very unlikely that a camera would do this if uses a mechanical shutter for video, but it can be practical in electronic shutter cameras.

Imagine a shutter speed of 0.5 seconds, and a framerate of 4fps. Each 'exposure' lasts 0.5 seconds, but each frame's exposure overlaps with neighbouring frames - the frames are not the same, but they overlap.

Imagine:

- A is the light value that arrives between 0 and 0.25 s
- B is the light value that arrives between 0.25s and 0.5s
- C is the light value that arrives between 0.5s and 0.75s
- D is the light value that arrives between 0.75s and 1s
- etc...

Then:

- Frame 1 contains the light A+B
- Frame 2 contains the light B+C
- Frame 3 contains the light C+D
- etc....

Comment: This only works if you have multiple sensors.  There is no physical way to "share" photoelectrons in the analog regime.  I don't think anyone's suggesting a post-processing partial sum of readout frames.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the physical shutter speed would have to be faster than the frame rate, but simulating overlapping exposures with a single sensor is certainly possible.